# Classify struct consisting of 3 `unsigned int` according to SysV ABI

Tags: assembly, x86, language-lawyer, x86-64, abi

I'm trying to classify the following struct:

```
struct test{
    unsigned a;
    unsigned b;
    unsigned c;
};
```

according to [AMD64 SysV ABI](https://www.uclibc.org/docs/psABI-x86_64.pdf)

---

Considering the following function:

```
struct test get_test(void){
    return (struct test){10, 20, 30};
}
```

We have the following compiled code:

```
Dump of assembler code for function get_test:
   0x0000000000000860 <+0>:     movabs rax,0x140000000a
   0x000000000000086a <+10>:    mov    edx,0x1e
   0x000000000000086f <+15>:    ret    
End of assembler dump.
```

It suggests that the whole `struct test` was classified as `INTEGER` and returned in `rax`/`rdx`. But the reason for this is not clear.

The classification of the `struct test` is started with classifying each of its eightbytes `AMD64 ABI/3.2.3`.

> If the size of the aggregate exceeds a single eightbyte, each is
>   classified separately. Each eightbyte gets initialized to class
>   `NO_CLASS`.

Each of the eightbyte is classified to have the `INTEGER` class `AMD64 ABI/3.2.3`:

> 4.Each field of an object is classified recursively so that always two
>   fields are considered. The resulting class is calculated according
>   to the classes of the fields in the eightbyte:
>
> [...]
>
> (d) If one of the classes is INTEGER, the result is the INTEGER.
>
> [...]

---

***QUESTION:*** What rule is used to classify the whole such structure?

I did not find a suitable one in here `AMD64 ABI/3.2.3`:

> 5.Then a post merger cleanup is done:
>
> (a) If one of the classes is MEMORY, the whole argument is passed in memory.
>
> (b) If X87UP is not
>   preceded by X87, the whole argument is passed in memory.
>
> (c) If the
>   size of the aggregate exceeds two eightbytes and the first eight- byte
>   isn’t SSE or any other eightbyte isn’t SSEUP, the whole argument is
>   passed in memory.
>
> (d) If SSEUP is not preceded by SSE or SSEUP, it is
>   converted to SSE.

Neither eightbyte of the struct is `MEMORY` nor `SSE` nor `X87` nor the whole struct exceeds two eightbytes.

Comment: If none of the `if`s matches, then the post merge is a no-op. It seems a straightforward classification to me: (INT+INT)+INT = INT hence the use of `rdx:rax`.

Comment: @MargaretBloom So the 4 bullet is related to classifying each eigthbyte (not just a field) as well as classifying the whole aggregate (merging each of the eightbytes of the aggregate)? If so this was not really clear from the wording of `4.`.

Comment: Each eightbytes (8Bs) is classified by itself, there can be at most 8 fields in an 8B. The class of the 8B is initially set to the class of the first field of the 8B, then current class and the class of the next, not yet analysed, field in the 8B are considered together to form the new class of the 8B (according to point 4). Repeat until all fields in the 8B have been analysed. Repeat until all 8Bs have been classified. Do the post merge (point 5). See this [simple mixed example](https://godbolt.org/z/oFYLyg) for an interesting case. Now, the only thing left are fields spanning two 8Bs ...

Comment: ... but there is an alignment check somewhere IIRC. I haven't untangled the algorithm completely, I still check a compiler if I need to return a struct. I believe that with a bit of patience and a few tests, one can fully understand the algorithm. I just never had the need to :)

Comment: @MargaretBloom _Repeat until all 8Bs have been classified._ So we classified all the 8Bs and in my example we have two `INT`s, but we do not classify the whole struct at that point. Since post merge is no-op is the whole struct classified by simply merging the 8Bs according to `4.`?